# How to optimize Scala double Call of Recursive Function

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I'm trying to get this Recursive Function to work:

```
@tailrec
def rec(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  if (n == 0) 0
  else if (n == 1) 1
  else (rec(n - 1) + rec(n - 2))
}
```

> Error:(13, 24) could not optimize @tailrec annotated method rec: it contains a recursive call not in tail position
>         else (rec(n - 1) + rec(n - 2))

How can this be optimized to work with tailrec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to write a tail recursive helper function:

```
def rec(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  @tailrec 
  def helper(n: BigInt, previous: BigInt, next: BigInt): BigInt = {
    if (n == 0) previous
    else if (n == 1) next
    else helper(n - 1, next, (next + previous))
  }
  helper(n,0,1)
}
```

This is, so you can pass the previous and next values of your sequence to the function, thereby allowing you to get only one call to your function.

This is a common pattern, as many recursive algorithms can only be made tail recursive through additional control flow mechanisms (for example: continuation passing). 
Factorial is another great example, where writing a helper function with an extra parameter is needed to make it tail recursive.

Comment: Let me just add that, in general, a tail-recursive (helper) method will always look like this: def helper(r: Result, w: Work) where Result and Work types are chosen to suit your problem. In this case, Result is BigInt and Work is (BigInt,BigInt). Clearly, you can untuple the Work as Luka did, but it doesn't change the basic idea. It might get a bit more complex if you have a quick-return condition, or some other special processing to do, but generally, it will look like this.